# Object Required error when attempting to concatenate one cell to the cell above

Tags: vba

This is the code i'm trying to run:

```
Sub AppendToCellAbove()

Dim Above As Range

Set Above = ActiveCell.Offset(-1)

With Above
    Above.Value = cell.Value & " " & ActiveCell.Value
    End With
    

End Sub
```

I have a basic understanding of a few coding languages (Python and Java) so any explanation would be really appreciated for my own learning.

Comment: `cell.Value` should be `Above.Value` and you do not need the `With`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. Put it in.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AppendToCellAbove()

    Dim Above As Range
    Set Above = ActiveCell.Offset(-1)

    With Above
        Above.Value = cell.Value & " " & ActiveCell.Value
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Now the code stops compiling, and the compiler is complaining about the `cell` variable being undeclared.

Without `Option Explicit`, VBA "declares" `cell` on-the-spot as a `Variant/Empty`. Because it's not being assigned anywhere, it's still holding a `Variant/Empty` value when the `.Value` member is invoked, at which point VBA says "wait a minute, that would have to be an object for that member call to be valid" and throws an error that just says "object required".

What it means is that you tried to invoke a member on an identifier that isn't holding an object reference.

With `Option Explicit`, you are now *forced* to declare all the variables you use, and undeclared identifiers (and typos!) become compile-time errors that are much easier to fix than run-time errors can be.

This would probably fix it (note the `With` block is qualifying `.Value` - if you explicitly qualify `Above.Value` then you don't need a `With` block):

```
Option Explicit

Sub AppendToCellAbove()

    Dim Above As Range
    Set Above = ActiveCell.Offset(-1)

    With Above
        .Value = .Value & " " & ActiveCell.Value
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I know i'm not supposed to comment ( or maybe i've got that wrong? the overflow guide says "please only post answers and mark one as the accepted, don't comment") but this was incredibly useful and thorough. I really appreciate it

Comment: Cheers - i'll look into rubberduck. Thanks again